# single feature probability in ERDAS object-oriented classification

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, erdas-imagine

I'm using ERDAS for my UAV image classification (consists 6 land cover types) and I performed the first step of Object-oriented classification, Single Feature Probability (SFP). It outputted a probability layer with value ranged from 0 to 1 indicating the similarity of every pixel to the training set.

However, it did not tell me the formula of how they calculated the SFP.

Could anyone give me a clue of it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SFP is the class probability derived from a [Bayesian Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), i.e. a statistical supervised classifier that can incorporate both continuous and discrete information. There is a hint on that in [this paper](http://www.gak.co.ke/nibs/web_resources/OBJECT-ORIENTED%20IMAGE%20CLASSIFICATION%20OF%20INDIVIDUAL%20TREES%20USING%20ERDAS%20IMAGINE%20OBJECTIVE-%20CASE%20STUDY.pdf).

Comment: Thanks radouxju. I have also came to the same article as well.